# Why does this midje test fail?

Tags: clojure

Here's my clojure function to try to reproduce the `filter` function:

```
(defn singleton? [coll]
  (= 1 (count coll)))

(defn my-filter [pred? a-seq]
  (if (singleton? a-seq)
    (if (pred? (first a-seq))
      a-seq)
    (if (pred? (first a-seq))
      (cons (first a-seq) (my-filter pred? (rest a-seq)))
      (my-filter pred? (rest a-seq)))))
```

And my the midje test is:

```
(my-filter false? [1 2 3]) => empty?        (actual return value is 'nil')
(my-filter even? [1 3 5 7]) => empty?       (actual return value is 'nil')
```

When I run midje, I get the error messages:

```
FAIL "my-filter" at (recursion.clj:54)
Actual result did not agree with the checking function.
        Actual result: nil
    Checking function: empty?

FAIL "my-filter" at (recursion.clj:57)
Actual result did not agree with the checking function.
        Actual result: nil
    Checking function: empty?
```

I'm pretty confused by this because when I run:

```
(empty? nil)
```

in a repl, I get 'true'.

Why is midje failing this test?

Comment: Do you know about destructuring?  I think you can clean up your implementation a bit.  Something like https://gist.github.com/dustinconrad/3b4326dae562c7ae0d83

Comment: So I just ran this locally, it works for me.  What version of Clojure/Lein/Midje are you using?

Comment: I'm using Leiningen 2.3.4 on Java 1.7.0_51 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM on OSX (don't know how to check the clojure version). Also I'm following https://iloveponies.github.io/ - we did do destructuring but not use 'when', etc. I'll refactor it though because destructuring is a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: in your project.clj you should see a dependencies keyword.  Check the clojure version there.  For example, :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.0.7"]
                 [org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.4"]]

Comment: It's (defproject recursion "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [iloveponies.tests/recursion "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :profiles {:dev {:plugins [[lein-midje "3.1.1"]]}})

Comment: I would try using clojure 1.6.0 (latest version of clojure).